# How to insert Small Caps in header using tcpdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, smallcaps

I am using TCPDF to create PDF documents. I want to use [small caps](http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?imgurl=http://diacritics.typo.cz/image.php%253Fname%253Duc-sc&imgrefurl=http://diacritics.typo.cz/index.php?id%3D85&h=175&w=400&tbnid=fbjd9YGmQrxiVM:&zoom=1&docid=Eii3iphwptaaBM&ei=UmqBVc6pD4LsUrO7gMgM&tbm=isch&ved=0CEsQMygnMCdqFQoTCM6a1sTflsYCFQK2FAodsx0AyQ) in my header, but I failed.

Here is my header code:

#### Version 1

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file ='image/pacra.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 100, 05, 20);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('times', 15);

        // Title
      $this->Cell(0,57, 'Trying To Use Small Caps', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false);
        $this->Line(10,32,200,32);
```

#### Version 2

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file ='image/pacra.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 100, 05, 20);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('times', 15);
        $str = 'Trying To Use Small Caps';
        $str = preg_replace("/([a-z]+)/e","strtoupper('<small>\\1</small>')",$str);
        $str= $this->writeHTML($str);
```

This code is working but I want to set XY axis of text.

Comment: Whatever string (Lower case / upper case) you pass to here same will display in header. To change case you can use php function strtolower($str).

Comment: @PraveenD Look at my updated code and suggest me please. I am very thankfull to you.

Comment: (please click on link)  For this you have to add fonts.

Comment: @PraveenD yes for (please click on link) this i want to add fonts. My updated code is working but here is a problem am not able to set XY axis of Text.

Answer (score 1):

Yahooo....!!!
I Solved my issue.

```
    <?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file ='image/pacra.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 100, 05, 20);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('times','B');
        $this->SetFontSize(16);
        //$this->SetTextColor(0,63,127);
        $this->SetXY(52,25);
        $str = 'Tying to Use Small Caps';
        $str = preg_replace("/([a-z]+)/e","strtoupper('<small>\\1</small>')",$str);
        $str= $this->writeHTML($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change font you need to add font style.
[Follow this for example.](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.phps)

```
// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
```

Comment: Dear i want to use Small Caps. How i can use this? i cant understand this example. i am new in php.

Comment: You said you want that font style.

Comment: Yes yes dear i want to set font style in Small Caps